# Angular 8 Default Routing

Tags: angular, routes, components, angular8

I have an app running Angular 8.2. The routing is working great, except for the default route.

When going to `website.com` I want to be redirected to `website.com/sign-in`

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'sign-in',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicLayoutComponent,
    data: { title: 'Public Views' },
    children: PUBLIC_ROUTES
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateLayoutComponent,
    data: { title: 'Private Views' },
    children: PRIVATE_ROUTES
  },
];
```

**public-routing.module**

```
export const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "sign-in",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../features/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(
        m => m.SignInModule
      )
  }
];
```

**private-routing.module**

```
export const PRIVATE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../features/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
        m => m.DashboardModule
      )
  }
];
```

I have also tried adding this to the **app-routing.module**

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'sign-in',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

**EDIT:**

All my routes work. When going to `website.com/sign-in`, angular looks at the **app-routing.module** then at the child routes to find where to route. If I add

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'sign-in',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

to the **public-routing.module**, anything except blank will redirect to sign-in. `website.com/jdjhjdfjd` will go to my sign in page, but `website.com` will not.

Comment: Hi.
i have the same issue.. did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to the fact that you haven't defined your sign-in route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'sign-in',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ...
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    component: SignInComponent,
    data: { title: 'Private Views' },
  },
];
```

Comment: I have it defined in the child component. The sign in rout works, my problem is the router not routing anything as a default.  `website.com/sign-in` will go to the sign in page, but the **app-routing.module** will not redirect any routes. Even if I add a path for both the child components so the link reads `website.com/public/sign-in`, the link works but the app router will not redirect from a blank route or a wild card route

Answer (score 0):

Because you have same urls in app-routing, they are overwritten by the last.
So the code you wrote is equivalent to(previous are overwritten by last because they have the same `path`)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateLayoutComponent,
    data: { title: 'Private Views' },
    children: PRIVATE_ROUTES
  }
];
```

And in angular you redirecting not for the `children`, but for the `path`
So there *must* be someк route with the `path: 'sign-in'`

If you want to use lazyloading here, there should be a path 'sign-in', which would have SignInModule module in children. And in the routing of this module there would be SingnInComponent for the `path: ''`

Answer (score -1):

You should check how to use Route Guards or you can use Router to redirect it:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['sign-in'])
  }
}
```